# Android - IP traffic statistics per application

Tags: android

Is it possible to get access to real-time IP traffic statistics generated by each application running on the Android?

Failing this, is there such thing as transparent proxy software that runs on the device that can collect this information?

Comment: You're asking about iPhone/iPad and you tagged the question as Android...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to get access to real-time IP traffic statistics generator by each application running on the the Android?

On newer Android devices, you can get per-app traffic statistics from `TrafficStats`.